# ace editor - passing mode to form input

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, erb, ace-editor

Ok so in my js Im setting my input value to a js value

```
$('input[name="mode"]').val(editor.session.getMode().$id);
```

this works fine in my new view form

```
<form id="snippetForm" action="/snippets/new" method="POST">
    <input class="hidden" type="text" name="mode" form="snippetForm"/>
</form>
```

passes the params to my controller

```
"mode"=>"ace/mode/ruby"
```

but when I do the same for my update form

```
<form id="snippetForm" action="/snippets/<%= @snippet.id %>/edit" method="POST">
    <input class="hidden" type="text" name="mode" form="snippetForm"/>

    <input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
</form>
```

on my params in conroller I get an empty string

```
"mode"=>""
```

Comment: Are they on the same page? Try naming one mode1 and seeing if that fixes it.

Comment: no they are in separate views when it renders the other doesnt exist and i also tried renaming already :( hat was my first thought

Comment: Its probably something to do with when jquery is ready vs when the dom is ready. Try setting a breakpoint in the browser before you set the value and see if $('input[name="mode"]') returns the value you think it should, or if its undefined at that point.

Comment: I'm sorry im brand new to js not quite sure how to do that

Comment: UPDATE: i did console.log and it spit out what I wanted so scope it fine

Comment: try something like $('input[name="mode"]').val(function(){console.log($('input[name="mode"]')); console.log(editor.session.getMode().$id);  return editor.session.getMode().$id}); that should allow you to see what the values are at assignment time. I bet one will be null/undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIGURED OUT THE ISSUE

I was setting the value on change of the session

```
editor.getSession().on("change", function () {

    $('input[name="mode"]').val(editor.session.getMode().$id);

});
```

problem was I made the dangerous assumption that changing the mode was considered a change event on the session. After some testing I noticed it worked but only when i typed in the editor before submitting. I changed to

```
$(document).click(function() {

    $('input[name="mode"]').val(editor.session.getMode().$id);

});
```

and all working